# approve/reject edits renders differently than the real deal

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

[C# SOAP Web Services client - example that shows how to log all raw SOAP intput and output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566855/c-soap-web-services-client-example-that-shows-how-to-log-all-raw-soap-intput-a/567011#567011)

@Thymine made an edit to improve the display of the first link. I reviewed and saw some text removed and an `ebay.com` URL in the post, and just hit the `reject` button. But when I followed the actual answer link, I saw that Thymine had indeed improved the original post: an URL was formatted incorrectly on the webpage, *but in the approve/reject dialog it looked fine*.

So I accidentally `rejected` a very useful edit. And I would feel better if I could blame the tool. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went ahead and [approved it](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/22416).

Keep in mind our html diff is good but not perfect for all uses, we can not fix a lot of super hairy diff like this ... I strongly recommend you try the markdown diff for hairy diffs like this.

[image: markdown is king]

Comment: Thanks Waffles! :) <3 the graphic, and I hadn't even thought to try it out yet.